# Это знак эквивалентности "==="?

Tags: javascript

Это знак эквивалентности "==="?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, это не знак, а оператор,
и не эквивалентности, а строгого равенства.

[Выражения и операторы Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)